# Issue when model changes within AJAX call in ngx-admin

Tags: angular2-components, angular2-changedetection

I downloaded the latest build of ngx-admin (https://github.com/akveo/ngx-admin), and served it up locally. In the `./@core/data/users.service.ts` file I have added the following method

```
  getHeroes (): Observable<any[]> {
    return this.http.get<any[]>('http://localhost:63468/api/clubs/heroes');
  }
```

That endpoint just returns some JSON like so:

```
[{"id":11,"name":"Mr. Nice"},{"id":12,"name":"Mr. Nice2"},{"id":13,"name":"Mr. Nice3"},{"id":14,"name":"Mr. Nice4"},{"id":15,"name":"Mr. Nice5"},{"id":16,"name":"Mr. Nice6"},{"id":17,"name":"Mr. Nice7"},{"id":18,"name":"Mr. Nice8"},{"id":19,"name":"Mr. Nice9"},{"id":20,"name":"Mr. Nice0"}]
```

In `./@theme/components/header/header.component.ts` I have added a click handler method:

```
  getHero() {
    this.userService.getHeroes()
      .subscribe(heroes => { 
        debugger;
        this.hero = heroes[0]
      });
  }
```

In `./@theme/components/header/header.component.html` I added a button and click event like:

```
  <button (click)="getHero()">
    add hero
  </button>
  {{hero?.name}}
```

I have done this to the same example project on Angular.io (https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6).

**The issue is:**

In the ngx-admin application, once that debugger line is hit, the `this.hero = heroes[0]` is properly set with the data I expect. Once the execution leaves that line of code, the view is not updated. If I inject `private ref: ChangeDetectorRef`, and call `this.ref.detectChanges();` immediately after `this.hero = heroes[0]`, then the view is properly updated. However, in the angular.io example of heroes, the view is properly updated within the context of the subscribe call. In that application no `this.ref.detectChanges();` is required.

Is there something in the ngx-admin project that is messing up the Angular change detection?

Comment: Could you please tell me how are you consuming `http`? `this.http.get` doesn't support  type arguments and you have used it as `this.http.get<any[]>`. It is giving a compile time error.

Comment: @ManojChalode https://angular.io/guide/http#type-checking-the-response